# iPhone, is there a tab char or some basic postion to show a string in a UITableView Row?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm putting together a basic UITableView before getting some feedback of how the data should look, if there a tab character or some way that I can split up the data in a string to make it look for tabular ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry.  The UILabel that holds that text isn't a terminal or a word processor and has no tab measures.  What you *can* do is use a `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle`, and place the date and amounts on the second line with `[[cell detailTextLabel] setText:[myObject dateAmountBalanceText]]`.  It won't look quite like you want it to, but it'll look better until you can build your own custom UITableViewCell.